# Entity Framework 5 Guid comparison results in no SQL being executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

What I have is a database with most tables keys being Guid's.  The problem is, if I try to do a LINQ to Entity statement and I compare a Guid that I have available to a Guid that exists in one of the Entities I'm referencing, the SQL is never run!  I've tested this using SQL Server 2008 R2 with SQL Profiler running and when doing the statement, the sql is clearly not ever making to the database.  If I take out the Guid comparison, then the sql is passed to SQL Server and I get a result back.

For instance:

```
var itemType = new Guid("27733204-C1E6-4F93-BEAD-63C2C8EBC299");
var items from myDBContext.Items.Where(x => x.itemType == itemType);
```

I've tried other methods such as x.itemType.CompareTo(itemType) but nothing works.  Essentially if I have a Guid I'd like to use in any type of Where clause that is outside the scope of the linq statement itself, I get absolutely no SQL being issued to the server.

I'm hoping someone has some answers.  Currently using Entity Framework 5 with C# 4.5.

Comment: Which version of .NET?

Comment: You are using single quotes where you should be using double quotes.  So I have the feeling you're not posting your actual code.  What you have here will not compile.

Comment: from provided code you are not evaluating linq expression: myDBContext.Items.Where(x => x.itemType == itemType). If it is an issue try myDBContext.Items.Where(x => x.itemType == itemType).ToArray();

Comment: @JefferyKhan You are correct - I was doing pseudo code as I cannot post the original.  I updated the quotes to be correct.

Comment: For the answer that I selected, one thing to note is the only change I made in my code was removing the Guid comparison - apparently when doing that the code does an eager get whereas having the Guids in there caused a lazy get.  Not entirely sure why that's the case, but either doing the foreach as Brian mentioned or doing a .ToList() at the end of the query statement did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 If I take out the Guid comparison, then the sql is passed to SQL Server and I get a result back.
```

From the description whatever code you changed caused the query to execute immediately.  LINQ methods support [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).  Deferred execution basically means that a query will not execute until the results are needed.  Generally methods that return a sequence use deferred execution.

`Where()` is one such method that uses deferred execution.  `Single()/SingleOrDefault()` execute immediately.  In other words, the latter types of methods execute immediately and therefore will cause SQL traffic visible in a profiler even without iterating the results.

```
            IEnumerable<Catalog> result;
            Catalog result2;
            using (var context = new ExampleEntities())
            {
                var itemType = new Guid("E8110BDE-8433-4C49-BA9A-034DEA2FA20E");
                result = context.Items.Where(x => x.ItemID == itemType);//deferred
                result2 = context.Items.First();//immediate

                //The foreach code below causes the deferred query to execute.
                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (var catalog in result)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", catalog.ItemID, catalog.ModifiedDate);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If I call a ToList() on this that should also force an execution so I'll give that a shot - I didn't even think about the deferred.  I'll get back with an update.

Comment: Actually Brian, that's the interesting thing.  Notice your result != null - that's where my major problem has been.  The result is always null and thus the foreach never gets run.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
// Create a sample item
var itemType = new Guid("27733204-C1E6-4F93-BEAD-63C2C8EBC299"); 

// Create a holder for the value of ItemType.
// EF will not be able to translate itemType.ToString()
// to SQL if you try to call it directly.
var itemTypeValue = itemType.ToString();

// Execute your query 
// I placed ToList() to force the
// execution.  You can use anything
// that will cause the query to enumerate.
var items from myDBContext.Items.Where(x => x.itemType == itemTypeValue).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't compile - can't do an == from a String to a Guid.